# Difference between "cater to" and "cater for"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

What is the difference between cater for and cater to? Not in the context of serving food.

Examples from Cambridge dictionary

- cater for someone/something:
  The college caters for deaf and visually-impaired students.

My understanding of the example

college meet the needs or demands of deaf and visually-impaired students?

- cater to someone/something:
  Our magazines cater to professionals such as lawyers and physicians.

My understanding of the example

It means our magazines contain what people want to read about like lawyers and physicians.

Comment: "Not in the context of serving food".  In what context is it.  What research have you done.  Can you find any examples of these expressions?  What do you suppose the difference to be?

Comment: Please look up and post the definition, at  least.

Comment: Thank you @JamesK and Lambie for your comments  I edited the main thread.

Comment: Cater for - more common in British English, cater to - more common in American English. That is a tendency, not a rule.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Brits used to [almost exclusively use ***for***,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=caters+to+them%2Ccaters+for+them&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=10), but over recent decades we've fallen into line with [the American preference for ***to***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=caters+to+them%2Ccaters+for+them&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=10)

Comment: What makes you think there's a difference? The examples you've found should show that the usage is parallel.

Comment: Are my explanations convey the meanings of cater to and cater for ?